# Multiple grep for a single array/ Faceted search

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a long array with multiple items per object and I have to start to exclude items depending on what someone selects as a check box, you can see a basic idea working here

http://jsfiddle.net/caseybecking/QwtFY/

My question is how do I start to narrow the list without having to do a check on how man y items they have checked, also this doesn't work if they check multiple items per "Fit" or "Wash"

To elaborate further my objectives. I need to store object(s) that only contain the specific item(s) the user wants to FILTER down to. All this is is a ginat filter of multiple pieces of a long array.

Comment: What you're trying to do isn't that clear. Your description is generic but the code is very specific. Either generalise the problem via the code or be more descriptive please.

Comment: Updated with a little more information. Any help would be amazing.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want something like `.serialize()` or `.serializeArray()` -- then you can send this data to your server or use the serialized array to filter the json object. You'll need to make sure each input element has a name attribute. In the below fiddle I've removed the hideous boxChecked function as haven't a clue what your trying to achieve in that. Anyway:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/zZtyy/

Comment: that might work, all work needs to be done client side no server side interaction.